# Reverse an array (Coloured shapes)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I currently have an array holding 5 different colours and I've got a for loop to loop through those colours and give them to a shape and display them.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var gc = canvas.getContext('2d');

var xPos = 25;
var yPos = 25;  

var colourArray = [];
    colourArray[0] = 'red';
    colourArray[1] = 'yellow';
    colourArray[2] = 'blue';
    colourArray[3] = 'magenta';
    colourArray[4] = 'green';

for(var count = 0; count < 5; count++){
    myColour = colourArray[count];
    xPos = 20+70*count;
    gc.beginPath();
    gc.rect(xPos, yPos, 50, 50);
    gc.fillStyle = myColour;
    gc.fill();
}
```

For the life of me I'm trying to figure a way to reverse this so it displays green first and red last.

Comment: When you type in `array reverse` in google, you get this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse You've nailed the keywords in your title.

Comment: Where would this go in my for loop?

Answer (score 0):

Just change what index you are accessing from the array based on the array's length. On your first iteration, you want to get the last item in the array (in this case, 4), and on the last iteration, you want to get the item at index 0. This code will work no matter how many colors you have in `colourArray`:

```
var length = colourArray.length;

for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    myColour = colourArray[length - (i + 1)];
    xPos = 20+70*i;
    gc.beginPath();
    gc.rect(xPos, yPos, 50, 50);
    gc.fillStyle = myColour;
    gc.fill();
}
```

Comment: @LeeMillward What's not working, exactly? Seems to work perfectly for me: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EXygZq

Answer (score 0):

```
var colourArray = [];
colourArray[0] = 'red';
colourArray[1] = 'yellow';
colourArray[2] = 'blue';
colourArray[3] = 'magenta';
colourArray[4] = 'green';

colourArray =colourArray.reverse();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.